# Material UI Tabs orientation property not working in react js component

Tags: material-ui

I am trying to set Material UI Tabs orientation with help of makestyle however background color is applied in root successfully but vertical orientation is not applied.

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: "blue",
    orientation: "vertical",
  },
}));

export default function SignInUp() {
  const tabStyle = useStyles();
  <TabContext value={value.toString()}>
    <Tabs
      value={value.toString()}
      classes={{ root: tabStyle.root }}
      indicatorColor="primary"
      onChange={handleChange}
    >
      <Tab value="1" label="Sign In" />
      <Tab value="2" label="Sign Up" />
    </Tabs>
    <TabPanel value="1">
      <SignIn></SignIn>
    </TabPanel>

    <TabPanel value="2">
      <SignUp></SignUp>
    </TabPanel>
  </TabContext>;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`orientation` is not a CSS property but a prop you have to pass to `Tabs` component, like this:

```js
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    background: "blue",
  },
}));

export default function SignInUp() {
  const tabStyle = useStyles();
  <TabContext value={value.toString()}>
    <Tabs
      value={value.toString()}
      classes={{ root: tabStyle.root }}
      indicatorColor="primary"
      onChange={handleChange}
      orientation="vertical"
    >
      <Tab value="1" label="Sign In" />
      <Tab value="2" label="Sign Up" />
    </Tabs>
    <TabPanel value="1">
      <SignIn></SignIn>
    </TabPanel>

    <TabPanel value="2">
      <SignUp></SignUp>
    </TabPanel>
  </TabContext>;
}
```

For more information you can look at the [API of Tabs component](https://material-ui.com/api/tabs/).

Comment: Many Thank for your time @Roman Mkrtchian !! I have done it as you suggest, it worked. However how can we achieve same by useStyles hook same like changing background color with css!!

Comment: Why do you want to do it with CSS ? I don't think it's a good idea as it would require several CSS rules, instead of just one component prop.

Comment: Well to learn more about material UI CSS way !!  You are right but I need to learn more way to change material UI